# How can I run a PHP IF clause within this already working PHP without breaking it?

Tags: php

This is like inception trying to run PHP within PHP and I'm stuck.

I have a working line of code

```
$select1.='<option value="'.$rss['po_number'].'">'.$rss['po_number'].'</option>';
```

I want to have an option selected if a certain MySQL value matches the option value.

Such as:-

```
$select.='<option value="'.$rs['su_name'].'"' if('.$rs['su_name'].'==='.$row['xero_supplier'].') echo 'selected="selected">'.$rs['su_name'].'</option>';
```

But I can't for the life of me work out how to make this work and my brain is fried.

Comment: Look into ternary operators if you're looking to make this a one-liner. Based on your novice confusion of basic PHP syntax, I recommend you not do the aforementioned.

Comment: You don't need to double execute PHP, just concatenate with ternary... but that's a mess to read and debug. It would look like `$select.='<option value="' . $rs['su_name'] . '" ' . ($rs['su_name'] === $row['xero_supplier'] ?  'selected="selected"' : '') . $rs['su_name'].'</option>';` answer below is better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I HIGHLY recommend breaking this into several lines of php code just for your sanity. Trying to cram too much logic into a single line leads to cognitive overload, and the whole point of code is to make machine logic human readable.

Consider:

```
  $select.='<option value="'.$rs['su_name'].'"';
  if ($rs['su_name'] === $row['xero_supplier']) {
     $select.=' selected="selected"';
  }
  $select.='>'.$rs['su_name'].'</option>';
```

This is building out this particular `option` html tag. It starts the tag to look like:

```
<option value="somevalue"
```

And then IF that condition is true adds to make it looks like:

```
<option value="somevalue" selected="selected"
```

And then finally ends the tag to make it look like:

```
<option value="somevalue" selected="selected">some_su_name</option>
```

Comment: If you *really* care about your sanity, use a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PHP Ternary operator
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

it allows you to write

```
if (a){
  return b;
} else {
  return c;
}
```

as

```
return a ? b : c
```

It would allow your code to become as such

```
$select.='<option value="'.$rs['su_name'].'" '.($rs['su_name'] === $row['xero_supplier'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$rs['su_name'].'</option>';
```